# Error using os.system/subprocess.run on Python (Spyder)

Tags: python, os.system

```
infilepath='D:/UTA/Research work/JunaidData/1996/New/'
outfilepath='D:/UTA/Research work/JunaidData/Output Jan 1996/'
mpefilepath=(infilepath+'xmrg01011996'+i[-3:-1]+'z')
os.system('./xmrgtoasc-i'+ mpefilepath+'> ' +outfilepath + 'MRMS01011996'  +i[-3:-1] +'z.asc')
shutil.move(mpefilepath+'.asc', outfilepath)
```

I have been provided the above script. The purpose is to convert a elf 64-bit lsb executable
(xmrgtoasc) to asc format.
However, the os.system line returns error '.' is not recognized as an internal or external
command, operable program or batch file.
Whereas, replacing os.system with subprocess.run retruns the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/UTA/Research work/JunaidData/1996/New/xmrg0101199600z.asc'
```

I have changed the path in system environment variable and performed measures found online but
still unable to run this. I am not proficient in python. Looking for help. Thanks

Comment: Initialize `i` so we can see what it is. Also, include the full traceback message. And for that second subprocess case, include a script for it also and its traceback. You could `print('./xmrgtoasc-i'+ mpefilepath+'> ' +outfilepath + 'MRMS01011996'  +i[-3:-1] +'z.asc')`. Now you can open a python shell and experiment with `os.system("whatever it was")` to see what's wrong.

Comment: File "C:\Users\Junaid\MRMS\No output.py", line 128, in <module>
    shutil.move(mpefilepath+'.asc', outfilepath)

  File "C:\Users\Junaid\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 805, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Users\Junaid\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 435, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\Junaid\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/UTA/Research work/JunaidData/1996/New/xmrg0101199600z.asc'

Comment: @tdelaney, this the traceback call when I run os.system.

Comment: i are the files in the infilepath which are required to be converted to asc.

Comment: Post the trace in the question for readability. Your tool may not understand forward slashes. Try backslash. Since python uses backslash as an escape, you need 2 in a row to make 1.

Comment: I already tried with backslash. It didn't work.

Comment: The outfile for /xmrgtoasc-i is different than the file you try to move.